# update a specific field in a filter queryset django without creating an instance

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a queryset which returns the first object of a model

```
latest_ignit_data = (  ignition_data
                      .objects
                      .filter(vehicle=veh_obj,updated_time_lt=new_time) 
                      .order_by('updated_time')
                      .first()
                    )
```

I would like to update the time field of this object, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**

This is **NOT** the way:

```
latest_ignit_data.update( updated_time =new_time )
```

Reading [django documentation, `first` raises a QuerySet evaluation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) because [`first` method is a convenience method equivalent to slicing.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#first)

Then, the **right way** is:

```
pk = (  ignition_data
                  .objects
                  .filter(vehicle=veh_obj,updated_time_lt=new_time) 
                  .order_by('updated_time')
                  .values_list('id', flat=True)
                  .first()
      )
ignition_data.objects.filter(pk=pk).update( updated_time =new_time )
```

This will update database without create instance and without raise signals.

Comment: surely you get a model instance not a pk value from `first()`, so the code above is still not quite right?

Comment: @Anentropic, `str( UF.objects.values_list('id',flat=True)[:1].query  )` returns
`'SELECT "ufs_uf"."id" FROM "ufs_uf" LIMIT 1'` Also a model is never created.  ( see [first](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L539) implementation )

Comment: my mistake, I didn't notice the `value_list` in the chain :)