# "Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken". Best practices?

Tags: python, django

Because of the nature of my project, I find myself constantly taking slices out of querysets, like so:

```
Thread.objects.filter(board=requested_board_id).order_by('-updatedate')[:10]
```

But this leaves me with the problem of actually DOING stuff with the elements that I have selected, because any kind of .update() or .filter() won't work after slicing.

I know of several ways to get around it, but they are all messy and confusing and seriously degrade the readability of the code, especially when I have to do it so often.

What's the best way to get around this slice-filter limitation?

Comment: This is a little broad. Can you give an example of the operations you want to do on it, and maybe some of your current workarounds which we might be able to improve?

Comment: For example: `Thread.objects.filter(board=requested_board)[:5].update(title='whatever')`. This WOULD work if not for the [:5] slicing. A current workaround consists of using `itertools.chain`, but that gives back an `itertools` object, which then has to be converted to a list to even be sent as a template context from a view. Works but it's very messy and unreadable.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4286144/2588818) covers that case, and is what I would suggest as well. Take the ids of your filtered & sliced queryset (using `value_list` or similar), and plug them back in to form a new query using `update`. A little ugly, but not Django's fault, as explained there (`UPDATE... WHERE... LIMIT...` is not OK in SQL).

Comment: Or you could use django-bulk-update, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28551658/3918774).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist actually you can simplify that - you don't need to take the IDs, you can just pass the queryset directly into `filter(id__in=sliced_queryset)`.

Comment: Would that double the number of database hits? My `itertools` solution doesn't, but it's uglier, and so far having to choose between ugliness and performance sucks a bit.

Comment: No, it will do it via a subquery: still a performance hit, but not as much as a whole other query.

Comment: @DanielRoseman wow, that's interesting!

Comment: @Man, slicing does not evaluate a `QuerySet` unless you use the `step` parameter, so using the way Daniel Roseman suggested is quite efficient and readable.

Comment: Cool, @DanielRoseman, did not realize that.

Comment: def get_queryset(self, request):
        limited_ids = Items.objects.order_by("-id").values_list("id", flat=True)[:3]
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).filter(id__in=limited_ids)
        return qs

Comment: There is a solution to a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29693386/12379095)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So far, based on the comments, I have found this solution by Daniel Roseman to be the least "ugly":

```
sliced_queryset = Somemodel.objects.filter(field='fieldvalue')[:5]
```

And then use `id__in=` to reference the sliced queryset objects' IDs:

```
Somemodel.objects.filter(id__in=sliced_queryset).update(field_to_update='whatever')
```

It works well, I've just tried it.

I wish Django had a more 'direct' way of doing this, but it's still pretty straightforward. If anyone has a better way, please post it and I will mark your answer as correct.

---

As a bit of extra advice, if you're using this to increment a field, like a 'views' field, you can self reference it cleanly like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

Somemodel.objects.filter(id__in=sliced_queryset).update(views=F('views')+1)
```